# Issues with transactions with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to write `@Scheduled` method that should make some operations with DB. In short, it should update data in table (add new records, rewrite existing records and delete unused ones. entity is defined by field `name`). After my first try I got something like `LazyInitializationException: No Proxy`. Annotate `@Scheduled` method with `@Transactional` annotation helped me a bit but now I have another problem: data overwriting looks like this:

```
Set<String> names = items.stream().map(Item::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
myService.deleteByName(names); //delete and save instead update
myService.save(items);
```

But now I get `ConstraintViolationException` because there is an unique key on column `name` and `myService.deleteByName(names)` doesn't have an effect (I think it is because this method is called from `@Transactional` method).

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you please share all of your code, as well as the exceptions you're getting?

Comment: Have you tried flush() after delete and then save?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate run the delete query after save opertion. So for your situation the delete query did not execute because of ConstraintViolationException. You can read [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-knowing-flush-operations-order-matters/).